# Function with 2 unknowns and one needs to be solved

Tags: quadratics

I have a homework question stating:

> Find the set of values of $k$ for which $f(x)=3x^2-5x-k>1$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

This question has really confused me because I looked at the answer and the value of $k$ is meant to be $k<-\frac{37}{12}$ and I'm afraid I don't know how to get there. May I please have some help?

Comment: What did you try to solve $3x^2-5x-k>1$?

Comment: Do you know how to complete the square?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Yes, I do know how to complete the square but all it gets me is k< 3(x-2.5)^2 - 7.5, when I try to rearrange for k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rearranging gives $3x^2-5x-k-1>0$, i.e. the resulting quadratic in $x$ has no real roots. This means that the discriminant $b^2-4ac$ must be negative:
$$(-5)(-5)-4\cdot3(-k-1)<0$$
$$25+12(k+1)<0$$
$$k+1<-\frac{25}{12}$$
$$k<-\frac{37}{12}$$
as expected.

Comment: This helped greatly, thanks! It really annoys me that I couldn't think of that, nor would I have ever probably thought of that so thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Consider the function
$$f(x)=3x^2-5x-k-1$$
Its derivative $f'(x)=6x-5$ is zero when $x=\frac 56$ and you want that $f\left(\frac{5}{6}\right) >0$.

Then, ....

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Completing the square we get $$\left(x-\frac{5}{6}\right)^2-\left(\frac{25}{36}+\frac{k}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\right)>0$$